# Play Mp3 when transaction completed

Tags: magento-1.9

We're trying to create a module that will play an MP3 in the backend of Magento 1.9 when we receive a completed transaction.

I've started by taking an existing module that checks for a new order and by default this module will email when observing the new transaction, I'd like to modify the action to play an mp3 instead if possible?

Comment: You can add javascript to the onepage success. Is the mp3 dynamic or always the same?

Comment: Hi the MP3 would stay the same but we wouldn't want it to play to the customer only in the back-end of Magento.